# Why does this slideshow change transition time when it reaches the end?

Tags: javascript, slideshow, transition

Hi I have made a basic slideshow which slides up every few seconds.

I've thrown in a if statement to roll this back to the start, why can I not get this to go back to the start quicker? It just seems to stay on the original transition time?

```js
var level = -300;

function slideshow() {
    var cont = document.getElementById('container');
    cont.style.transitionDuration = "3s";
    cont.style.transform = "translate(-0px," + level + "px)";
    level = level - 300;

    if (level == -900) {
        flipback()
    }
}

function flipback() {
    level = 0;
    cont.style.transitionDuration = "1s";
    cont.style.transform = "translate(-0px," + level + "px)";
    slideshow();
}

setInterval(slideshow, 6000)
```

```css
body {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
#display {
    width:450px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:150px 450px;
}
#container {
}
#container img {
    height:300px;
    width:450px;
    padding-right:0px;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="display">
    <div id="container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xwLyn0t4/#&togetherjs=HwEh0cnDCy

Comment: Please include the relevant code **in** your post. Use StackSnippets of possible. Also your code has an error, it doesn't run at all: `Uncaught ReferenceError: cont is not defined`.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can’t change the transition time like that. I’ve made a slideshow myself and ended up using two different elements for controlling the positioning (`translate` in your case) — one that has a smooth (and slow) scroll and another one without the smoothness (or a quicker scroll as in your case). Only then it was possible to change the translation independently with independent speeds, etc. But in the end it was a robust and relatively simple solution.